# In TaskJuggler, how to manage multiple projects running in parallel

Tags: pm-software, reporting, multi-projects

I manage three different projects with TaskJuggler. These project share some of the resources.

I follow these [suggestions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/taskjuggler-users/qYSJoOND3aw) and created three different .tjp files.

I'm fine for my individual reports, but I don't know how to combine the exports to be able to create global reports.

Is it the recommended solution for this problem. And if yes how can I combine the exports?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! We don't get a lot of TaskJuggler questions here, so it may take awhile to get a response. The question certainly looks on topic; I just retagged it to hopefully get the right eyeballs to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone encountering this question, this is how I do it:

1. Create an overall project file like allmyprojects.tjp
2. Include all needed tji files with
   *include "path-to-tji" {taskprefix sub1}*
   By specifying taskprefix you can have the tasks with the same ID in subprojects.
3. Schedule allmyprojects.tjp
4. In allmyprojects.tjp you can specify reports just as in the normal tjp

Caveats:

- The project duration in allmyprojects has to cover all subprojects
- If you have overlapping bookings of a common resource in the subtasks,
  scheduling will stop with an error message. So you yourself have to
  take care that this does not happen, but the message tells you exactly where the conflict happens
- Also, shared resources should have the same name in all projects. I have
  common resource, holiday and report files for all projects that I just
  include.

In the subproject directories I also have a leave.tji file, where I specify leaves to other projects that I do not control.Of course, the scheduling of allprojects.tjp will look different from the individual ones as soon as they share resources and you may have to change the subprojects to get a schedule. But after all that is the reason to schedule all of them at once...

HTH